# Word doc processing in AWS lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, ms-word

Any AWS gurus out there... Is it possible for a lambda function to update a table/text in a Word Document? The document is stored in AWS S3 bucket.

Most of the google searches have yielded conversion from .docx to pdf and nothing about editing the doc itself.

Comment: If you can do this programmatically on Linux then you can probably do this in AWS Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

This is **very** possible with some coding. Build your Lambda function with the Java run-time API. Then use a Java LIB like this one to perform Word manipulation.

https://poi.apache.org/components/document/quick-guide-xwpf.html

(there are no AWS examples that show this exact use case that i can point you to)

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful